# How can I do this source transformation/Reduce this circuit?

Tags: current-source, voltage-source

I've seen and solved many examples but I'm stuck here . Maybe I'm confused as to what is parallel and what is in series here. [image]

I can do the transformations up to the 1A current source but I can't isolate a parallel resistance for it so I can transform. It's most likely simple . Can I add it with the current source on the left as if it has zero resistance ?[image]

PS:This is from the unsolved problems section of a textbook I'm studying and it is no homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like homework so I'm not going to give you a full solution, but I will tell you that the next step is to convert the 4A current source with parallel resistor into a voltage source with series resistor.

EDIT: After getting a 2A current source in parallel with 20 ohms, the next step is to combine the 2A and 1A sources. Current sources in parallel add, just like voltage sources in series.

By the way, the voltage is 40V, not 4V.

Comment: Of course that's how it goes. I'm sleep deprived I guess. Thanks. It's not homework, I'm studying a textbook and it's in the unsolved problems sections.

Comment: A little more help would be very much appreciated, I'm stuck again.

Comment: The current source can be again converted to a voltage source with a series resistor, then you get two voltager sources with their series resistors in parallel

Comment: @JohnKatsantas Updated.

Comment: So I can add the two sources even though there is resistance in between?

Comment: It's not really "in between". The two sources and the resistor are in parallel. You can draw them in whatever order you want; the important thing is that the two sources are connected to the same pair of nodes.